# Normalizer of a subgroup generated by a cycle.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $H$ be the cyclic subgroup of $S_4$ generated by the cycle $(1234)$.

> What is the order of the normalizer $N$ of $H$ in $S_4$?  Give generators for $N$.

How do I go about solving a problem like this?  We have $H = \{(1), (1234), (13)(24), (4321)\}$.  I've seen a formula for $[S_4 : N]$ as $\frac{s}{r}$, where $s$ is the number of elements in $S_4$ in the same conjugacy class of $(1234)$, and $r$ is the number of elements in $H$ with the same cycle type as $(1234)$.  So $s = 6$, and $r = 2$, so $\frac{s}{r} = 3$, and $|N| = \frac{24}{3} = 8$.  What is a good way to find the generators of $N$?

My guess would be $N$ would be generated by $(1234)$ and any transposition, say $(12)$ (assuming $N \cong D_8$).

Comment: $$(12)(1234)(12)^{-1}\notin H\implies (12)\notin N$$ But, for example, check that $\;(12)(34)\in N\;$ ...

Comment: @D_S From the way you define $r$ and $s$ it seems $r=s$ because the number of elements in the same conjugacy class as $(1234)$ is exactly the number of elements with the same cycle type of $(1234)$ (in $S_4$).

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

By Lagrange, and since $\;H\le N\;$, it must be that $\;|N|\in\{4,8,12,24\}\;$

Show that $\;|N|=12\implies N=A_4\;$ , and thus it *must* be $\;|N|=8\;$ since $\;(12)(34)\in N\setminus H\;$

Now prove

$$(12)(34)(1234)(12)(34)=(1234)^{-1}\implies N\cong D_8\;$$